# "mi kaj X" aŭ "X kaj mi"?

Tags: culture, word-order

When listing people and one of them is oneself (i.e. the first person singular pronoun), it's common in some languages and cultures (among them English and German) to **list oneself last**, or at least not first. Mentioning oneself first is even often considered impolite, probably because it is perceived as egocentric or even egoistic or narcissistic.

Do these same conventions also apply in Esperanto and in the Esperanto culture?

I.e.:

**Is it common in Esperanto to list oneself last, or at least not first?**

Is listing oneself first deemed impolite or inconsiderate in Esperanto culture?

I began wondering about this because Duolingo has the translation excercise sentence

> [Mi kaj mia gasto vespermanĝas kune.](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/9123359)

and as sample solution

> My guest and I eat dinner together.

Note that the English sentence has "I" and "my guest" swapped relative to the Esperanto sentence. It is quite uncommon for Duolingo sample solutions to change the order of listed items in a phrase part, even when the order semantically doesn't matter, so this stood out to me and seemingly also to others as it has sparked [a little discussion](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/9123359?comment_id=9666076) in the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no conventions that I know of.

La kunliga vorto *kaj* estas sufiĉe neŭtra. Jen kelkaj ekzemploj Zamenhofaj el Tekstaro:

*mi* unue:

```
tiam ni – mi kaj Marcello–
mi kaj ili dormadis
mi kaj li estas gefianĉoj
Por mi kaj la fratino! (kun prepozicio)
```

*mi* laste:

```
nur li kaj mi sciis
Ŝia patro Kaj mi – ni ambaŭ staros
Karolo kaj mi ofte kantadis
Ĉu ili ambaŭ havas tian saman valoron kiel vi kaj mi?
```

Tio ankaŭ validas por *aŭ*:

*mi* unue:

```
kiu venkis? mi aŭ ŝi?
mi aŭ la redakcio de “La Revuo” volas...
```

*mi* laste:

```
kian komprenon vi aŭ mi havas pri la libereco
Se tio estus iu el ni, vi aŭ mi,
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that Esperanto is for the whole world, I doubt, that there are any steadfast rules for this. Personally I consider *Mi kaj mia gasto...* as neutral, the reversed order somehow emphasizing.

Comment: re emphasizing: Is that due to "mia gasto" relating to "mi"? Would it be different for "Adamo kaj mi" vs. "Mi kaj Adamo"?

Comment: Good point. I think, you're right. _Mi kaj mia gasto_ but _Adamo kaj mi_: